# My nordic forms updates fine, but my pro part of form wont update

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Problem is, my Nordic part of form updates and syncs (POST and GET) fine. But for some reason my Pro part of form gets the values needed, but does not POST them to PHP or PHP does not update them. Not sure which, but I know that it gets stuck somewhere after "submit" button is pressed.
I set the variables for the nClicks and pClicks, which is Nordic and Pro. I Submit the values with JavaScript. On button click I add or subtract to Nordic or Por counter. I receive the amount from database and later by pressing "save" I'm updating the database.

```js
    var pClicks = <?php echo $pro ?>;
    var nClicks = <?php echo $nordic ?>;

     function mySubmit() {
     document.getElementById('pro').value = pClicks;
     document.getElementById('nordic').value = nClicks;
     document.getElementById("proForm").submit();
     document.getElementById("nordicForm").submit();
   }

    function pJuurde() {
        pClicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("pClicks").innerHTML = pClicks;
    };

    function pMaha() {
        pClicks -= 1;
        document.getElementById("pClicks").innerHTML = pClicks;
    };

    function nJuurde() {
        nClicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("nClicks").innerHTML = nClicks;
    };

    function nMaha() {
        nClicks -= 1;
        document.getElementById("nClicks").innerHTML = nClicks;
    };
```

```html
<form id="nordicForm" action="nordicSave.php" method="post">
  <input  id= 'nordic' name='nordic' value='nordic' />
  </form>
  <form id="proForm" action="proSave.php" method="post">
  <input  id= 'pro' name='Pro' value='pro' />
  </form>

<button type="submit" onclick="mySubmit()"> Salvesta </button>
</body>

<?php
            include("testmysql.php");

            $pro = $_POST["pro"];
            $db->query("UPDATE mastid SET pro = $pro");

            header("Location: index.php");

?>

<?php
            include("testmysql.php");

            $nordic = $_POST["nordic"];
            $db->query("UPDATE mastid SET nordic = $nordic");

            header("Location: index.php");

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <form id="nordicForm" action="nordicSave.php" method="post">
  <input  id= 'nordic' name='nordic' value='nordic' />
  </form>
  <form id="proForm" action="proSave.php" method="post">
  <input  id= 'pro' name='Pro' value='pro' />
  </form>
```

I deleted 1 form tag and made it into only one form. like that.

```
<form id="proForm" action="proSave.php" method="post">
<input  type="Hidden" id='pro' name='pro' value='pro' />
<input   type="Hidden" id='nordic' name='nordic' value='nordic' />
</form>
```

It worked wonders